# Best way to insert 18000+ rows using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a script that parses a csv file that has 18000+ rows in it. At the moment my code builds up a SQL statement of the format:

```
INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (..., ..., ...)
```

When I output the compiled SQL and run it in the database directly I get the following:

```
Error in Processing Request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error
```

I think the data is valid as I did a direct import via phpmyadmin just to test the initial file. I also did a smaller test of my code with a smaller version of the final file and that worked fine.

So my question is have I created a SQL query that is too long to run and if so is there a better way to do this?

As an aside this code is being executed from the backend of WordPress which is where the file upload function will live.

Would love to get some feedback on this.

Comment: if you execute just one manually, does it work?

Comment: do you insert all of them in the same query? or one per each  of the 18000 rows?

Comment: Have you checked the server error logs to get more info?

Comment: 18.000 rows aint that much, could you share the code you are using?

Comment: Also check max_packet_length : http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,161869,161998#msg-161998

Comment: Error 500 is an http error code, not a mysql error code. Check your webserver logs

Comment: maybe there is: "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" (you need to set ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000); ===>3000=time)

Comment: direct import from CSV will be better

Comment: @SpongePablo which would be better. I have them all in the same single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement which reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
[REPLACE | IGNORE]
INTO TABLE tbl_name
[CHARACTER SET charset_name]
[{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
    [ESCAPED BY 'char']
]
[LINES
    [STARTING BY 'string']
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
]
[IGNORE number LINES]
[(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
[SET col_name = expr,...]
```

Comment: This route is the way to go